# Riak on Windows

Tags: erlang, nosql, riak

I want to play with Riak http://riak.basho.com/ or a least get it running on a Windows system. I have downloaded the source code and compiled it but that's where I get stuck, how do I start it?

Comment: Did you ever get Riak installed on Windows? I am interested in doing the same.

Answer (score 17):

It does run, altough I havent managed to run it as a service yet.

Install CYGwin, install latest erlang, get source code, compile in cygwin

then the fun part, adjust according to your paths and place into a batch

c:\riak\rel\riak\erts-5.7.4\bin\erl -boot c:\riak\rel\riak\releases\0.8\riak -embedded -config c:\riak\rel\riak\etc\app.config -args_file c:\riak\rel\riak\etc\vm.args -- console

Regards

Comment: Do you have any step by step instructions I could follow to get Riak onto windows?

Comment: Ok, I am going to try this now

Comment: Kyle C. Quest shows in a video that it can be ported. It seems he did not publish his modifications? Here is his video: http://vimeo.com/29764118

Comment: J. Peschka explains some difficulties he sees in doing a windows port here: http://riak-users.197444.n3.nabble.com/Windows-tt3757870.html#a3760693

Answer (score 10):

Looks like the riak source has several bash start scripts. You would have to convert those to a windows batch script equivalent. That could be a fairly interesting chore given how limited batch scripts are. Those start-*.sh files show how to start it up though so I'd start there.

The http://hg.basho.com/riak/src/tip/README Readme file has futher info on what each script does.

Answer (score 1):

Riak can not be run on Windows, only on Linux and Mac.

Comment: If you can send me a link for Riak on Windows I would very much appreciate it, and then I will be happy to be disproved :)

Comment: After all that I read it seems difficult to port it and it is not supported by basho, but that does not mean it's impossible to write and maintain a port.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to run VMWare or VirtualBox and run Riak inside a Linux VM.  Works great for me.

Answer (score -1):

Running it inside docker instance works very well - this is in 2017 the only way to successfully run Riak on Windows. You could probably get something running using Cygwin but this will be very complex and unreliable. Running under Docker is currently the most idiomatic solution.